# SVN repo corrupted

Tags: svn, version-control, svn-administraton

I have a repository which I can add files to, but when I try to commit or checkout the repository (to any version) I get the error 'Could not convert '�⛰ENDREP' into a number'

I have no idea what is going on, I don't really want to loose the history from my repo by having to re-create it. I last committed yesterday and went to commit at the end of the day today (after adding one file) and now it appears to be corrupted.

Can anyone explain what has happened and how it can be fixed?

**Edit:**
I am using TortoiseSVN 1.9.2, Build 26806 - 64 Bit

Comment: So is it a working copy or a repository?

Comment: @bahrep - it's repo, with very old SVN under hood on server and old (pre 1.7?!) SVN-client: http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.subversion.devel/127106 https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/tortoisesvn-dev/UMnwWMEqb9Y https://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/subversion-dev/201104.mbox/%3CBANLkTimDxrTbMnz62Z33uCrVroz0YeNaeg@mail.gmail.com%3E Must be fixed in 1.7 release of TSVN

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>You have damaged repository.</strike>

In order to fix it you (or SVN-admin, better) have to have access to server and run `svnadmin verify` for testing repository and `svnadmin recover` if there are errors detectedIt seems as rather old version of TortoiseSVN (pre-1.7) with ancient version of SVN on the repo-side like 1.3 ([source](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.subversion.devel/127106), [source](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/tortoisesvn-dev/UMnwWMEqb9Y), [source](https://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/subversion-dev/201104.mbox/%3CBANLkTimDxrTbMnz62Z33uCrVroz0YeNaeg@mail.gmail.com%3E))

Comment: I set up the repository using the TortoiseSVN right click extention. Will this method still work?

Comment: @Mike159 - local repo, created with TSVN is complete repository anyway

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite get what you mean

Comment: @Mike159 - OK. "Don't worry, do it"

Comment: What I meant was I don't know how to run svnadmin verify or recover. (I am on Windows not Linux if that helps)

Comment: `svnadmin` is part of CLI SVN-tools, which you have to have installed with TSVN. Just run `svnadmin help` from command-prompt window for details

Comment: It looks like that it's working copy, not a repository.

Comment: Running svnadmin verify gives: "E200004: Could not convert '??ENDREP' into a number"

Recover says it is complete and that the most recent version is 41, but it doesn't actually fix anything

Answer (score 0):

Ok, svnadmin verify produced the ENDREP error (E200004) and recover didn't do anything. I have managed to change the current version file in the actual repository to the previous version, checked out again and re-added my changed files from my local copy. Everything seems to be working now, hopefully that will be the last of it.